# Cannot compile flutter app for iOS due to 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found error

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I'm working on a flutter app, as part of a team, and we recently decided to add Share Extension to our app to allow iOS users to share media from outside the app.

After adding the Share Extension, I was able to compile the app and run it. But sometime after that (switching to different git branches) I started getting this error persistently:

```
 Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/m4/2cb6zdx138q5z5x0ljnvmygm0000gn/T/flutter_tools.VWykU0/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirylPO5Z/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    /Users/jyotiproy/IdeaProjects/krew_app/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h:1:9: note: in file included from /Users/jyotiproy/IdeaProjects/krew_app/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h:1:
    #import "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"
            ^
    /Users/jyotiproy/IdeaProjects/krew_app/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:10:9: error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^
    1 error generated.
    <unknown>:0: error: failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/jyotiproy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bgkxbehdnpdmkjfwhnujcqssvqjc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/Runner-Bridging-Header-swift_2R9KITIRJQAWU-clang_13QX7MSDXGS1W.pch' for bridging header '/Users/jyotiproy/IdeaProjects/krew_app/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h'
    /Users/jyotiproy/IdeaProjects/krew_app/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h:1:9: note: in file included from /Users/jyotiproy/IdeaProjects/krew_app/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h:1:
    #import "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"
            ^
    2 errors generated.
    error: generate-pch command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    /Users/jyotiproy/IdeaProjects/krew_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.4.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/jyotiproy/IdeaProjects/krew_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.4.99. (in target 'Reachability' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/jyotiproy/IdeaProjects/krew_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.4.99. (in target 'OrderedSet' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/jyotiproy/IdeaProjects/krew_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.4.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/jyotiproy/IdeaProjects/krew_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.4.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController-TOCropViewControllerBundle' from project 'Pods')

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/m4/2cb6zdx138q5z5x0ljnvmygm0000gn/T/flutter_tools.VWykU0/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirylPO5Z/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Error (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
/Users/jyotiproy/IdeaProjects/krew_app/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:9:8

Error (Xcode): failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/jyotiproy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bgkxbehdnpdmkjfwhnujcqssvqjc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/Runner-Bridging-Header-swift_2R9KITIRJQAWU-clang_13QX7MSDXGS1W.pch' for bridging header '/Users/jyotiproy/IdeaProjects/krew_app/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h'


Error launching application on Krew iPhone.
```

I've tried some solutions to this error that I found here on SO, like: [This one, that suggests removing the ios folder and recreating the project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66722481/7327464) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65577277/7327464)

I've found success once with the first solution (deleting the ios folder), but when I recently tried it again, it didn't work.

I am currently on Xcode 13.3 and below is the output of flutter doctor.

```
❯ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.0, on macOS 12.2 21D49 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 3.0.0 at /Volumes/macOS_Ext/Library/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision ee4e09cce0 (6 weeks ago), 2022-05-09 16:45:18 -0700
    • Engine revision d1b9a6938a
    • Dart version 2.17.0
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Volumes/macOS_Ext/Library/Android
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-11.0.13/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.13.8.1 (build 11.0.13+8-LTS)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Volumes/macOS_Ext/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2022.1.2)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin version 68.1.4
    • Dart plugin version 221.5787.37

[✓] VS Code (version 1.68.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.42.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-x64     • macOS 12.2 21D49 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 102.0.5005.115

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

I'm adding a link to our project's Podfile (as requested in the comments). It can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/kGfzHGJW).

Comment: Can you post your Podfile here

Comment: @KaushikChandru Here's a link to the Podfile : https://pastebin.com/kGfzHGJW

Comment: There are 3 empty strings above  target.build_configurations.each do |config| in Podfile. Is that mandatory?

Comment: @KaushikChandru removed them and tried to compile the app again. But it's still giving me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the issue using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66722481/7327464) answer. Now I have mentioned in my question that this method was not working for me and I think I understand why.

After recreating the ios folder, I used to do a git rollback to "un-delete" the icons and some xcode project settings. But that was what I did wrong. What one's supposed to do instead is start with a fresh ios folder and add the necessary files and settings manually (also double-checking them in the process) in xcode. After I did that, I was able to compile the app. Hope this helps someone in the same situation.