# Xcode 14.3 Failed to emit precompiled header 'Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h'

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, precompiled-headers

[image]

I fail to emit precompiled header issue when I try to build an IOS app through Xcode. Currently, my Xcode (14.3) and the app I am running is in Flutter (3.7.10). Can anyone please provide me with a solution?

Comment: did you try deleting the derived data followed by clean build and then run

Comment: I haven't deleted the derived data can you provide me some references to do it

Comment: it is shown in the error.
`/Users/imac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`

Comment: I deleted the derived folder data and clean the build and then running but still facing the same issue

Answer (score 2):

Go to -> iOS/Pods -> Target Support Files -> Pods-Runner -> Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh

and then add

```
-f
```

in

```
source="$(readlink "${source}")"
```

like this

```
source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"
```

then delete iOS/Podfile.lock file,

also delete derived data,

and then run these commands one by one in flutter/iOS folder:

- flutter clean
- sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
- pod deintegrate
- rm -rf Pods
- pod cache clean --all
- pod setup
- pod install --repo-update

your problem should be solved now !

Comment: if we do `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods` then how does all below commands related to `pod ....` would work?

Comment: You can install cocoapods again by running the command "sudo gem install cocoapods" if you're facing any error but I think "pod setup" command should do the job.