# Flutter.h not found, and failed to emit precompiled header, Runner-Bridging-Header.h

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

I have the same problem as here: [Flutter.h not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76012528/xcode-14-3-failed-to-emit-precompiled-header-runner-runner-bridging-header-h)
but using Xcode 15:

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
.../GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:9:8
```

And

```
Error (Xcode): failed to emit precompiled header
.../ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h
```

I was hopeful that the above would solve it, but no.

Losing hours on this, and not for the first time - the solution seems to be different each time, despite the problem symptoms being the same.

```
flutter doctor                      
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.6, on macOS 13.6 22G120 darwin-arm64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.83.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

Very frustrating. Any help appreciated :)

I have tried / checked this:
[image: flavor soln]

From: [Github flavorizor issue](https://github.com/AngeloAvv/flutter_flavorizr/issues/197)

And:
[image: SO soln]
From: [SO soln 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76012528/xcode-14-3-failed-to-emit-precompiled-header-runner-runner-bridging-header-h)

As well as working through the items here:
[SO failed to emit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45779591/failed-to-emit-precompiled-header-for-bridging-header)

Answer (score 0):

I can't be absolutely sure that this was the only change, but I think it made the difference, Step 2 from [this link](https://franktheprogrammer.com/blog/flutter/troubleshooting-xcode-15-build-issues-flutter)

Here's a screenshot of it
[image: Update build phases]